# How to clone Ionic project to production

Tags: plugins, ionic-framework, gulp

I have an Ionic Project, with all plugins, and libs and I am a little lost on how to manage so many plugins and libs.

Sometimes I install a plugin, test and after that install a couple of other plugins, and so on. After some time, I have so many plugins and I don´t remember what are useful and what are not useful.

So, I would like to create another folder with a fresh version of my project, with only the necessary plugins and libs.

I am now using gulp to minify and uglyfy my code, and I will put all my minified files in this new folder.

So, my questions are:

- Is there a simple way to verify what are the plugins and libs really necessary, without need to see it one by one ?
- Is there a way to clone all my original project to another one, after I have already cleaned up the original folder ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- when you adding a plugin, you should call

  `ionic plugin "plugin-name" --save`

  it will save plugin information to your `config.xml` and `package.json`

  next time, when your run `ionic build`, if plugins not install, it will  auto install necessary plugins.
- about npm module, you should call `npm install "package-name" --save-dev` to save your develop module, like `gulp`

in new project, you just copy the `package.json` and change project name and information, then call `npm install`, it will install the saved module.